# Error replacing tomcat with jetty in a springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jetty

I am trying to remove tomcat from my springboot application and add jetty instead. I removed tomcat dependency from my application and added jetty but it is not working.

My pom.xml -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Getting below error -

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.context.MissingWebServerFactoryBeanException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory' available: Unable to start AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean
2022-06-16 13:59:09.671  INFO 3247 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-16 13:59:09.690 ERROR 3247 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.

Action:

Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a `@Bean` for the new `JettyServletWebServerFactory`:

```
// Create bean of type ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() 
{
  JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
  factory.setPort(9000);
  factory.setContextPath("/myapp");
  factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notfound.html"));
  return factory;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Same Error